# Presentation API PresentationRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to integrate this API: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/presentation-api/
with my project.

However, it always generates this error in the browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PresentationRequest is not defined

It was perfectly fine if I create a new project with just 2 html to test out the controller and web presentation.

Is it due to javascript conflict with my project's .js files?

Comment: It is more likely to be a "scoping" issue rather than a "conflict" but we can't help specifically because you haven't shown the actual, relevant scripts.  What does "just 2 html" mean?  I couldn't correct that part when I was editting.

Comment: Are you sure you're not testing in a browser that doesn't support `PresentationRequest`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PresentationRequest